# How to mock just constructor of Class in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have some class like this

```js
class Foo {

    constructor() {...}

    public bar() {...}
}
```

I want to test just `Foo.bar` without calling `Foo`'s constructor. How can I mock just that?

Note: I need an instance of `Foo`, as `bar` uses a few instance variables.

Comment: Whatever you're thinking about doing, don't. If you want to mock it without calling the constructor, then maybe the methods you want to test should be static instead of instance?

Comment: I think there is a case to test a method without calling a constructor. Say the constructor does some business logic you want to get in a separate test. Why should you mix unit tests?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant - what you're describing is the entire purpose of why dependency injection exists.

Comment: What code exists in your constructor that would mess with your test? Could you post a little bit more real-world rather than hypothetical code? It will help determine the best course of action in testing what you want are trying to test. Mocking methods of a class is ok, mocking a constructor really smells like you should be using dependency injection, but it's hard to say exactly.

Comment: Can you test it by calling `Foo.prototype.bar()` directly? Otherwise, need more info to identify the question.